# Can this function be rewritten as a Ramda pipe? How?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I want to know if it is possible to rewrite `A` as a Ramda pipe where `D` waits on `C` without passing the result of `C` into `D`:

```
const A = async payload => {
    const resultB = await B(payload);
    const resultC = await C(resultB);
    const resultD = await D(resultB);
    return resultB;
};
```

Edit: this doesn't seem to be producing desired results:

```
const R = require('ramda');

const then = R.curry((f, p) => p.then(f));

const trace = R.curry(async(name, data) => `${name}(${data})`);

const B = trace('B');
const C = trace('C');
const D = trace('D');

const A = async payload => {
    const resultB = await B(payload);
    await C(resultB);
    await D(resultB);
    return resultB;
   };

const A_Pipe = R.pipe (B, then(C), then(D));

A('x').then(console.log); // -> B(x)

A_Pipe('x').then(console.log); // -> D(C(B(x)))
```

Answer (score 4):

Apparently [Ramda plans to add `R.then`](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/pull/1906) but it looks like they haven't gotten around to it yet

Until then, you can make your own

```
const then = 
  R.curry((f, p) => p.then(f))

const A =
  R.pipe(B, then(C), then(D))
```

Here's a complete program you can paste in the [Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20then%20%3D%20f%20%3D%3E%20p%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20p.then%20%28f%29%0A%0Aconst%20effect%20%3D%20f%20%3D%3E%20x%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20%28f%20%28x%29%2C%20x%29%0A%20%20%0Aconst%20trace%20%3D%0A%20%20effect%20%28console.log%29%0A%0Aconst%20fakeFetch%20%3D%20x%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20new%20Promise%20%28r%20%3D%3E%20setTimeout%20%28r%2C%20200%2C%20x%29%29%0A%0Aconst%20B%20%3D%20x%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20fakeFetch%20%28trace%20%28%60%5BB%3A%20%24%7Bx%7D%5D%60%29%29%0A%0Aconst%20C%20%3D%20x%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20fakeFetch%20%28trace%20%28%60%5BC%3A%20%24%7Bx%7D%5D%60%29%29%0A%20%20%0Aconst%20D%20%3D%20x%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20fakeFetch%20%28trace%20%28%60%5BD%3A%20%24%7Bx%7D%5D%60%29%29%0A%20%20%20%20%0Aconst%20A%20%3D%0A%20%20pipe%20%28B%2C%20then%20%28C%29%2C%20then%20%28D%29%29%0A%0AA%20%281%29%0A%2F%2F%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20Promise%20%22%5BD%3A%20%5BC%3A%20%5BB%3A%201%5D%5D%5D%22%20%7D)

```
const then = f => p =>
  p.then (f)

const effect = f => x =>
  (f (x), x)

const trace =
  effect (console.log)

const fakeFetch = x =>
  new Promise (r => setTimeout (r, 200, x))

const B = x =>
  fakeFetch (trace (`[B: ${x}]`))

const C = x =>
  fakeFetch (trace (`[C: ${x}]`))

const D = x =>
  fakeFetch (trace (`[D: ${x}]`))

const A =
  pipe (B, then (C), then (D))

A (1)
// => { Promise "[D: [C: [B: 1]]]" }
```

Output

```
[B: 1]
[C: [B: 1]]
[D: [C: [B: 1]]]
```

---

**I see what you did there**

Upon closer inspection, `C` and `D` are side-effecting functions whose return value is discarded – `resultC` and `resultD` are not used. Rather, `resultB` is the only value you seem to care about

```
const A = async payload => {
  const resultB = await B(payload)
  const resultC = await C(resultB)
  const resultD = await D(resultB)
  return resultB
}
```

When composing functions with `R.compose` or `R.pipe`, the return value of one is passed to the next. In your case however, `C` and `D` should not impact the input. I introduce `asyncTap` to encode your intention – compare to [`R.tap`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#tap) or `effect` above

```
const asyncTap = f => p =>
  p.then (R.tap (f))

const A =
  pipe (B, asyncTap (C), asyncTap (D))

A (1) .then (console.log, console.error)
// => { Promise "[B: 1]" }
```

Output – see complete program in the [Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20asyncTap%20%3D%20f%20%3D%3E%20p%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20p.then%20%28R.tap%20%28f%29%29%0A%0Aconst%20trace%20%3D%0A%20%20R.tap%20%28console.log%29%0A%20%20%0Aconst%20fakeFetch%20%3D%20x%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20new%20Promise%20%28r%20%3D%3E%20setTimeout%20%28r%2C%20200%2C%20x%29%29%0A%0Aconst%20B%20%3D%20x%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20fakeFetch%20%28trace%20%28%60%5BB%3A%20%24%7Bx%7D%5D%60%29%29%0A%0Aconst%20C%20%3D%20x%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20fakeFetch%20%28trace%20%28%60%5BC%3A%20%24%7Bx%7D%5D%60%29%29%0A%20%20%0Aconst%20D%20%3D%20x%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20fakeFetch%20%28trace%20%28%60%5BD%3A%20%24%7Bx%7D%5D%60%29%29%0A%20%20%20%20%0Aconst%20A%20%3D%0A%20%20pipe%20%28B%2C%20asyncTap%20%28C%29%2C%20asyncTap%20%28D%29%29%0A%0AA%20%281%29%20.then%20%28console.log%2C%20console.error%29%0A%2F%2F%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20Promise%20%22%5BB%3A%201%5D%22%20%7D%0A)

```
[B: 1]
[C: [B: 1]]
[D: [B: 1]]
[B: 1]
```

This begs the question: what *are* you doing with `resultC` and `resultD`? Functional programming is about writing programs with pure, side-effect-free functions. When you're having difficulty expressing your program in a functional way, it can sometimes indicate you're not thinking in a functional way.

---

Comment: Yes, that is the Ramda plan.  The PullRequest fell behind a major Ramda change, and it hasn't been brought back up.  But I expect to get that back in in the next few weeks.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be producing the desired result. See edited answer for details.

Comment: @SpecialBlend I included a complete program in my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Not ramda, but it does what you want.

```js
const { pipe, tap } = require('rubico')

const A = pipe([
  B,
  tap(C),
  tap(D),
])
```